# my excerpts lack the 'more' link

Tags: theme-development

on a site am writing, on the home page i want to achieve the following

- Posts should appear as excerpts with links to full article
- Editors should have the power to explicitly control excerpt length

I tried the following solution:

- create template file called home.php
- use the_excerpt() in the loop

The problem
'read more' link is missing if user specifies explicit 'more' `<!--more-->` when creating a post but strangely if explicit 'more'  is not specified in post, the link to full article is available. What the hell is going on?
[image][image][image]

Comment: I was able to reproduce the effect in Twenty Eleven; possibly caused by the $more variable not being set, as I could fix it by adding `global $more; $more = 1;` before the loop in home.php. interestingly, the more-link keeps showing if the excerpt code is used in index.php.

Comment: Pretty interesting. Is it a bug in twenty eleven theme or what

Answer (score 1):

If you want to output the `$post->post_content` you need to use `the_content()` function, `the_excerpt()` function outputs `$post->post_excerpt`, so if the post doesn't have content on the excerpt field it doesn't output nothing.

A better solution should be a custom function that first checks for a user defined `$post->post_excerpt` and second for the `$post->post_content` and outputs the first defined.

Comment: The problem is not that it outputs nothing. Rather that there is no link to full article if an explicit `<!--more--> link is specified. I find this surprising

Comment: I am going tobe forced to add it manually .....echo '<a href="';the_permalink();echo '">More...</a>';

Answer (score 1):

The actual documentation for this is here:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More

Read the following section:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More#Read_More_Techniques